# What is the difference between ActiveRecord transaction block of instance and a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I am using `Active Record Transactions` in my current task. I was able to done my job in the both the ways I mentioned below. But I am not clear that there are any differences, calling `transaction` method on `instance` and `class`.

I have gone through the Rails [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), but did not notice any differences.

> What is the difference between following two usages of `transaction` method?

```
Account.transaction do
  balance.save!
  account.save!
end

balance.transaction do
  balance.save!
  account.save!
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no difference, the instance method simply delegates the execution to the class method. Here's the code:

```
def transaction(options = {}, &block)
  self.class.transaction(options, &block)
end
```

Comment: Understand! Thanks @mrodrigues

Comment: No problem! In the future, if you want to check the implementation of any method, just use this: `balance.method(:transaction).source_location` and `Account.method(:transaction).source_location`; you'll receive the location, just open the file and check how it's implemented.